# Determine if $f(x)+x_0+x_n$ is balanced

Tags: encryption

> If $f(x)=x_0x_1\oplus x_1x_2\oplus\cdots\oplus x_{n-2}x_{n-1}\oplus x_{n-1}x_n\oplus L(x)$ is a balanced boolean function (which is a boolean function whose output yields as many 0s as 1s over its input). Determine if $f(x)\oplus x_0\oplus x_n$ is balanced.    Notice that $L(x)=k_0x_0\oplus k_1x_1\oplus k_2x_2+\cdots\oplus k_nx_n$, where $  k_i \in \{0,1\}$.

Newly to this field. Any hints would be helpful.

Comment: Please add some additional info to your question about what you have tried / where you're stuck or if something is unclear. Otherwise this question might be flagged as low quality.

Comment: Does it  $L(x)$ or $L(k,x)$? What is info about k`s

Comment: It can be any $L(x)$ such that $f(x)$ is balanced .

Comment: If I can specify any $L(x)$, then $f(x)$ can be any balanced function (because, for any balanced function, I can pick $L(x)$ appropriately to make $f(x)$ that balanced function).  Perhaps it is assumed that $L(x)$ is linear?

Comment: As your function $f$ is quadratic, you can use the algorithms in section 3 of the recent preprint "Correlation of Quadratic Boolean Functions: Cryptanalysis of All Versions of Full MORUS" (http://ia.cr/2019/172) to check if $f$ is balanced.

Comment: @poncho: $L(x)$ of the form given in the last line of the yellow box are always linear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to learn about your new field, I strongly recommend you to read *only* section 3 of [Correlation of Quadratic Boolean Functions: Cryptanalysis of All Versions of Full MORUS](http://ia.cr/2019/172), maybe skipping the proofs but definitely *not* the examples during the first reading.

Try then to solve your problem for at least an hour, before reading my solution below. (Hint: Apply Algorithm 1 (no need to program it) to your function $f$, and then Lemma 4 to the result of Alg. 1.)

---

As a self-contained answer would be much too long, I assume that the reader understood section 3 of the paper mentioned above.

Following Algorithm 1, define $x'_0 := x_0+x_2$ then $x'_2 := x_2 + x_4$, and so on, and additionally (don't look at the $k'$ before you understood about the $x'$) $k'_0 := k_0, k'_{2i+1} = k_{2i+1}, k'_{2i+2} := k_{2i+2}+k_{2i}$ to clean up the linear term L  to get

$$f(x'_0, x_1, x'_2, x_2, \dots) = x'_0x_1 + x'_2x_3 + \dots + x'_{m-1}x_m + k'_0x_0 + k'_1x_1 + \dots + k'_nx_n,$$

in disjoint quadratic form, where $m=n$ if $n$ odd and $m=n-1$ if $n$ even.

Lemma 4 tells you now that kodlu is right in claiming that $f$ cannot be balanced if $n$ is odd, as *all* variables $x'_0, x_1, x'_2, \dots$ show up in some quadratic term (that are separated after the substitution).

Lemma 4 tells you also that for $n$ even, $k'_n = k_n+k_{n-2}$ being $1$ is equivalent to $f$ being balanced, as $x_n$ is the only variable *not* showing up in any quadratic term (that all are separated over the variables $x'_0, x_1, x'_2, \dots$).

For $n$ even adding $x_n$ to $f$ corresponds to replacing $k_n$ by $k_n+1$ making $k'_n=0$ and $f$ *not* balanced.

Adding then $x_0$ to $f$ corresponds to replacing $k'_i$ by $k'_i+1$ for *all even* indices $i$, in particular also for $i=n$ even, making $k'_n=1$ and $f$ balanced again.

Answer (score 1):

Experimentally, the claim seems to hold, for odd number of variables so even $n$ (you have $n+1$ variables), which I have tested until $n=6$.

It also holds vacuously for even number of variables since none of them satisfy the condition of the theorem, i.e.,
$Q(x)+L(k,x)$ is not balanced for any $L(k,x)=\sum_i k_i x_i,$ all sums being modulo 2.

I don't have a proof. Induction may work starting at $n=2,$ i.e., for $x=(x_0,x_1,x_2)$ and $Q(x)=x_0 x_1+x_1 x_2.$

Comment: "The XOR sum of any two balanced functions is balanced"; is this true?  $f(x) = x_0$ is balanced; so is $g(x) = \bar{x_0}$, however $f(x) \oplus g(x)$ is not...

Comment: Oops. Except when one is a complement of the other, then? Do you see the error in my proof?

Comment: Actually, one can come up with other examples where the two functions are not complements of each other, for example, $f(x) = x_0$ and $g(x) = x_0 \oplus x_1x_2x_3...x_n$,  As for your proof, the error is in the last line; we actually have $n_{01} + n_{10} = 2(2^n - t)$, which you haven't shown will be $2^n$

Comment: In the picture you just added, the shaded part of the line you labeled $f \oplus g$ is actually $\bar{g}$

Comment: @poncho, boy I feel dumb!